# Duda sobre concatenar listas de strings

Tags: python, funciones

tengo que escribir una funcion que transforma una lista de listas con nombres y apellidos,
en una única lista con cada nombre y apellido concatenados
pude juntar las listas con un append, el tema es que no se como quitarle la , que en este caso sería el separador, hasta ahora lo que tengo es esto

```
def transformarnombres(lista1,lista2):
    listavacia=[]
    listavacia.append(lista1)
    listavacia.append(lista2)
    print(listavacia)

print(transformarnombres(["hola","sabelo"],["como","estas"]))
```

esto debería retornar ["hola sabelo","como estas"]

Comment: si haces lista1 + lista 2 se concatenan

Comment: se concatenan en una sola lista sí, pero yo quiero quitarle la coma, o sea, quiero quitarle la coma a la lista 1 y a la lista 2, y que al final me devuelva una nueva lista con, la lista 1 sin comas una coma como separador y la lista 2 sin comas

Comment: Tenes que recorrer cada sublista, conseguir ambas cadenas y concatenarlas poniendo un espacio en medio. Un ejemplo de esto ultimo usando suma sería cadena1 + " " + cadena2

Comment: Entonces haz esto:  *lista1, *lista2

Comment: o sea las recorro, el tema es que no se como conseguir ambas cadenas, despues concatenarlas es facil

Answer (score 0):

```
def transformarnombres(lista1,lista2):
    print(*lista1,*lista2)

print(transformarnombres(["hola","sabelo"],["como","estas"]))
```

Con la siguiente solución debería extenderte bien las listas

Comment: Esta respuesta crea una sola lista con el patron "nombre, apellido, nombre...". El op quiere concatenar el nombre y el apellido en una sola cadena.

Comment: Además, [las respuestas que son solo código no suelen ser bien recibidas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: Basicamente he hecho lo que ha pedido en su post

Comment: El OP pide retornar una lista con dos elementos `["hola sabelo","como estas"]`.

Comment: No juzges un libro por su portada (en especial aqui, que los titulos a veces son como "me ayudan con esto?"). Si lees solo el titulo, si, pareciera pedir eso. Pero si lees el cuerpo de la pregunta y en particular el ejemplo final, pide otra cosa a la descrita en tu respuesta. Quiza el OP se expresó mal.

Answer (score 0):

```
def transformarnombres(lista1,lista2):
    temp1       =   ''
    temp2       =   ''
    temp3       =   ''
    listavacia  =   []
    listavacia2 =   []
    
    for i in lista1:
        temp1    =  temp1 +   str(i) +" "
    for j in lista2:
        temp2    =  temp2 +   str(j) +" "
    
    listavacia.append(temp1)
    listavacia.append(temp2)
    
    for k in listavacia:
        temp3   =   k[:-1]
        listavacia2.append(temp3)
    return  listavacia2

print(transformarnombres(["hola","sabelo"],["como","estas"]))
```

En teoría debería funcionar, no lo hice con mucha elegancia por el tiempo, pero funciona con tus listas y con más.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Una solución:

```
def transformarnombres(*listas):
    return [' '.join(x) for x in listas]
```

Esta función recibe una cantidad indeterminada de listas. El "*" delante del parámetro indica a Python que debe reunir todos los parámetros de la llamada en una sola lista llamada `listas`.

Luego recorro la super-lista extrayendo cada lista (`for x in listas`). Cada `x` es una lista, y uso `join()` para concatenar sus elementos.

#### Demo

```
def transformarnombres(*listas):
    return [' '.join(x) for x in listas]

print(transformarnombres(["hola","sabelo"],["como","estas"]))
```

produce:

```
['hola sabelo', 'como estas']

Process finished with exit code 0
```